# r: using purrr::safely to handle webscraping failed urls

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I am trying to webscrape a few pages with `rvest` and `purrr::map`. However, I am not sure how to use `purrr::safely` to handle failed links. Take the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
urls <- list("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Barcelona",
             "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome",
             "lkjsadajf")
h <- urls %>% map(~{
  Sys.sleep(sample(seq(1, 3, by=0.001), 1))
  read_html(.x)})
```

I get the following understandable error:

```
Error: 'lkjsadajf' does not exist in current working directory ('/home/user').
```

How do I use `purrr::safely` or any other error-handling function to produce a list with the html of all `urls` that work and with a `NA` with the `urls` that don't?

---

**EDIT**

As an extension to the question above: the `safely` function produces a nested list. How to handle the output of `safely` for it to be handled by `rvest::html_nodes`?

```
library(dplyr)
out <- h %>% map_df(~{
  a <- html_nodes(., "#firstHeading") %>% html_text()
  a <- if (length(a) == 0) NA else a
  b <- html_nodes(., ".toctext") %>% html_text()
  b <- if (length(b) == 0) NA else b

  df <- tibble(a, b)
})
out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to wrap the `read_html` with `safely` and specify `otherwise` as `NULL` or `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
safe_html <- safely(read_html, otherwise = NULL)
h <- urls %>% 
       map(~{
         Sys.sleep(sample(seq(1, 3, by=0.001), 1))
         safe_html(.x)})
```

We can remove the `NULL` elements and proceed with

```
discard(h, ~ is.null(.x$result)) %>%
        map_df(~ .x$result %>% {
        a <- html_nodes(., "#firstHeading") %>%
              html_text()

        b <- html_nodes(., ".toctext") %>% 
              html_text()
        rowr::cbind.fill(a, b, fill = NA)

        } )
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But safely produces a nested list, which changes how the output is handled by the rvest functions. I edited my question to make it more complete. You know how to feed the output of safely to the rvest functions?